# the line is repainted in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to draw a line based on a few points that come with the help of a setinterval, I'm passing the points one at a time but I could also pass several. for now I want the points of the line to be drawn one at a time but without re-drawing those that have already been drawn. How can I solve this problem ?

[image]

http://plnkr.co/edit/JjIiqrf97Y8K7YUJRodo?p=preview

```
  var path=g.selectAll(".line1")
  .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "line1")
    .attr("d", function(d,i) { return (line(data)); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return "brown" });
```

in my real problem, I will receive points in real time that is why I am practicing how to draw point to point and generate an animation

Comment: cos you draw path, why not draw only the last array? why you want to do this? what you want to achieve?

Comment: @KEKUATAN I hope you can help me. I just want to draw point to point. in my real problem, I will receive points in real time that is why I am practicing how to draw point to point and generate an animation

Answer (score 0):

Its because of your loop. You are pushing to `datos` and then rerendering the entire array.

```
  var datos = new Array();
   setInterval(function(){
    if(datos.length<newPoints.length){

      datos.push(newPoints[count]);
      count++;

      // Here you are rerendering this new piece of data,
      // AND all of the previous pushes of data.
      display(datos);
    }
   }, 1000);
```

Comment: No, this does not work. the line is repainted from the beginning